# MethodCallExpression is not setting up the orderby correctly

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I'm new to this expression business. I am modeling after this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637(v=vs.110).aspx

I am trying to get a list of my offices that satisfies a specific name. The code works up to the point that I need to setup the order by. I keep getting this error:

```
ParameterExpression of type 'DB.Office' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.String'
```

Here is the code

```
        IQueryable<Office> offices = GetAllOffices();
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Office), "Office");
        Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(Office).GetProperty("OfficeName"));
        Expression right = Expression.Constant(filterRequest.Filters.Value);
        Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(left, right);

        Expression predicateBody = e1;

        MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new Type[] { offices.ElementType },
            offices.Expression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<Office, bool>>(predicateBody, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

        MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "OrderBy",
            new Type[] { offices.ElementType, offices.ElementType },
            whereCallExpression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string>>(pe, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

        IQueryable<string> results = offices.Provider.CreateQuery<string>(orderByCallExpression);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns a `Office`, so you should

```
IQueryable<Office> results = offices.Provider.CreateQuery<Office>(orderByCallExpression);
```

Note that your `OrderBy` is wrong...

it should probably be something like:

```
MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "OrderBy",
    new Type[] { offices.ElementType, typeof(string) },
    whereCallExpression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<Office, string>>(left, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));
```

if you want to order by `OfficeName`. What you wrote was: `.OrderBy(x => x)` that is quite useless, because rows of a table don't have an ordering. I have rewritten it as `.OrderBy(x => x.OfficeName)`

Perhaps you want to add a `.Select(x => x.OfficeName)` after the `OrderBy`

```
MethodCallExpression selectCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Select",
    new Type[] { offices.ElementType, typeof(string) },
    orderByCallExpression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<Office, string>>(left, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));
```

Then it really is:

```
IQueryable<string> results = offices.Provider.CreateQuery<string>(selectCallExpression);
```